# Converting to a dictionary with values from dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe.

|  | City | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Paris | 10200000 |
| 1 | Beijing | 202000 |
| 2 | New York City | 2000 |

I want to convert it to a list to this format.

```
Cities = [
    {"Paris": 10200000},
    {"Beijing": 202000},
    {"New York City": 2000}]
```

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just do a list comprehension:

```
Cities = [{c:v} for c,v in zip(df['City'], df['value'])]
```

Output:

```
[{'Paris': 10200000}, {'Beijing': 202000}, {'New York City': 2000}]
```